# Laravel validation for composite key

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-8

I am validating a field before inserting or updating but what I want to validate is, to validate in my table with the foreign key instead of the primary key.
My model of aution is:

```
class Auction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'auction_number',
        'title',
        'description',
        'image',
        'catelogue',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'start_time',
        'end_time',
        'status'
    ];
    // public function auction_category(){
    //     return $this->belongsTo(category::class,'category','id');
    // }

    public function lot(){
        return $this->hasMany(Lot::class,'auction_id','id');
    }
}
```

My model of lot is:

```
class Lot extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'auction_id',
        'lot_number',
        'category',
        'description',
        'min_price',
        'max_price',
        'current_bid',
        'asking_bid',
        'thumbnail',
        'image',
        'sold',
        'closed'
    ];
    // public function seller(){
    //     return $this->belongsTo(Seller::class,'seller_id','id');
    // }
    public function auctions(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Auction::class,'auction_id','id');
    }
    public function singlecategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo(category::class,'category','id');
    }
```

then below is the controller of lot where I need these validations:

```
public function update(Request $request, Lot $admin_lot) {
    $this->validate(
    $request, 
    [   
        'auction'=> 'required',
        'lot_number'=> 'required|unique:lots,lot_number,'.$admin_lot->auction,
        'category' => 'required',
        'description'=> 'required|min:75',
        'min_price'=> 'required|numeric|regex:/[0-9][0-9]+/u',
        'max_price'=> 'required|numeric|regex:/[0-9][0-9]+/u',
        'image.*'=> 'sometimes|nullable|file|image',
    ],
    [   
        'auction.required'    => 'Please Select Auction Number, Thank you',
        'lot_number.required'      => 'Please Select Lot Number, Thank You.',
        'description.required' => 'Please Enter Description, Thank You.',
        'description.min' => 'Please Enter Minimum of 75 Characters In Description, Thank You.',
        'min_price.required'      => 'Please Enter Min price, Thank You.',
        'min_price.numeric'      => 'Please Enter a Valid Min price Without Any Special characters, Thank You.',
        'min_price.regex'      => 'Please Enter Valid Min Price, Thank You.',
        'max_price.required'      => 'Please Enter Max price, Thank You.',
        'max_price.numeric'      => 'Please Enter a Valid Max price Without Any Special characters, Thank You.',
        'max_price.regex'      => 'Please Enter Valid Max price, Thank You.',
        'image.image'      => 'Please Select Image, Thank You.',
        ]);
//then rest of my functions
if ($request->file('image')) {
            if (File::isDirectory(public_path($admin_lot->image))) {
                File::deleteDirectory(public_path($admin_lot->image));
                File::deleteDirectory(public_path($admin_lot->thumbnail));
                $hashpath = 'public/lot/images/lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time();
                $hashpaththumb = 'public/lot/thumbnail/lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time();
                foreach($request->file('image') as $imagefile){
                    if (!empty($imagefile)) {
                        $imagepath = $hashpath.'/'.'lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time().'.jpg';
                        $thumbnailpath = $hashpaththumb.'/'.'lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time().'.jpg';
                        $image = Image::make($imagefile)->resize(265,275)->encode('jpg');
                        $thumb = Image::make($imagefile)->resize(60,45)->encode('jpg');
                        Storage::put($imagepath, (string) $image->encode());
                        Storage::put($thumbnailpath, (string) $thumb->encode());
                    }
                }   
                $imageurl = Storage::url($hashpath);
                $thumburl = Storage::url($hashpaththumb);
            }else{
                $hashpath = 'public/lot/images/lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time();
                $hashpaththumb = 'public/lot/thumbnail/lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time();
                foreach($request->file('image') as $imagefile){
                    if (!empty($imagefile)) {
                        $imagepath = $hashpath.'/'.'lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time().'.jpg';
                        $thumbnailpath = $hashpaththumb.'/'.'lot_'.uniqid().'_'.time().'.jpg';
                        $image = Image::make($imagefile)->resize(265,275)->encode('jpg');
                        $thumb = Image::make($imagefile)->resize(60,45)->encode('jpg');
                        Storage::put($imagepath, (string) $image->encode());
                        Storage::put($thumbnailpath, (string) $thumb->encode());
                    }
                }   
                $imageurl = Storage::url($hashpath);
                $thumburl = Storage::url($hashpaththumb);            
            }
        }else{

            $imageurl=$admin_lot->image;
            $thumburl =$admin_lot->thumbnail;
        }
        $admin_lot->update([
            'auction_id'=> $request->auction,
            'lot_number'=> $request->lot_number,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'description'=> $request->description,
            'min_price'=> str_replace(',', '', $request->min_price),
            'max_price'=> str_replace(',', '', $request->max_price),
            'thumbnail'=> $thumburl,
            'image'=> $imageurl
        ]);

        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Lot updated successfully!',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
        return redirect()->back()->with($notification); 
}
```

Here from the above code, the auction is the foreign key I have stored in the lots table and the auction is the primary key from the table auctions. So what I want is to have unique lot numbers for each auction for example:

```
auction 1 can have lot numbers 1,2,3,4, etc
auction 2 also can have 1,2,3,4,5 etc
```

but from the above case, auction 1 can not have repeated numbers 1,2,3,4 since they have already been assigned to this same auction number 1. So how may I add validation for this since what I have tried is validating the primary key for example:

```
auction 1 from above has the 1,2,3,4 and if I assign these to auction 2 then it gives an error saying it is already taken but the auction is different,
```

so it has to take them as valid. So how can I do this pls someone help me to get this done

Comment: lot no. are stored comma separated ?

Comment: no one after another like : aution 1 lot 1 and in second aution 1 lot 2 like this

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: Please add codes of controller and model

Comment: What i have added is my controller code and inside my controller fisrt part is validation and second part is store or update. So i can even add the full function

Comment: Hi @LeenaPatel I have added my both the models and the lot controller

Comment: In my question auction is the primary key of auctions and that is  the foreign key in my lot table. So in my lot table I can have any number of auctions right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use closure [laravel custom validation using closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures)

```
$auction = $request->input('auction');
$validated = $request->validate([
    'lot_number' => ['required',function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($auction) {
        if(Lot::where('auction_id', $auction)->where('lot_number', $value)->exists()){
            $fail('Given lot no. is already exists');
        }
        
    }],
]);
```

Comment: Your answer is working well for insert but how can we do it for update? could you please let me know that too? for edit it gives error even if i don't change the current lot number

Comment: i have guided you how to give custom validation using closure. now its upto you how you define logic in closure for update according to your requirment.

Comment: Sorry I asked a foolish question again. I achieved this with another where condition and passed the current lot id in the use method of closure. Thank you so much it works fine for both the insert and  with one more where conditon to exclude the current id in update function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rule::unique` to achieve your validation rule

```
$this->validate(
$request, 
[   
    'auction'=> 'required',
    'lot_number'=> ['required',
         Rule::unique('lots')->where(function($query) {
              $query->where('auction_id', '!=', $request->auction)
                    ->where('lot_number','!=',$request->lot_number);
         })            
     ],
    'category' => 'required',
    'description'=> 'required|min:75',
    'min_price'=> 'required|numeric|regex:/[0-9][0-9]+/u',
    'max_price'=> 'required|numeric|regex:/[0-9][0-9]+/u',
    'image.*'=> 'sometimes|nullable|file|image',
]
// other code
```

Comment: Ma'am it is not working.But the actual code has to work for insert function but it is not working it gives me error saying the lot number is already taken but the taken lot number is for another auction

Comment: You can use conditional unique rule. See my edited answer.